# Getting ERROR: invalid transaction termination CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function run(text,text,text,double precision) line 147 at COMMIT

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, transaction

I am trying to execute an `INSERT` statement and, if there's an error then I rollback and retry the insert; otherwise I  commit it to close the transaction. However, I am getting the error: "invalid transaction termination".

The below code is converted code from Oracle to PostgreSQL.

```
    sql_cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        step_id, sql_text, exit_on_exception, error_code, error_message, always_run
        FROM ifm_app.sql_for_batch
        WHERE batch = p_batch AND step_id > beginstep
        /* 0 */
        ORDER BY step_id;
    SELECT
        COALESCE(MAX(step_id), 0)
        INTO STRICT beginstep
        FROM ifm_app.sql_for_batch_log
        WHERE insert_date = (SELECT
            MAX(insert_date)
            FROM ifm_app.sql_for_batch_log
            WHERE batch = p_batch AND error_code = 0) AND batch = p_batch AND error_code = 0;
    currentstep := 0;
    /* How many step will run? */
    SELECT
        COUNT(*), MAX(step_id)
        INTO STRICT stepcount, maxstep
        FROM ifm_app.sql_for_batch
        WHERE batch = p_batch AND step_id > 0;

    IF maxstep = beginstep THEN
        /* means, that previsious run was done successfully */
        beginstep := 0;
        /* batch will run from beginning */
    END IF;

    IF beginstep = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO ifm_app.sql_for_batch_log_archive
        SELECT
            *
            FROM ifm_app.sql_for_batch_log
            WHERE batch = p_batch;
        DELETE FROM ifm_app.sql_for_batch_log
            WHERE batch = p_batch;
    END IF;
    /* set_parameter('^^P_STRING^^',p_string); */

    FOR sql_rec IN sql_cur LOOP
        currentstep := currentstep + 1;

        IF sql_rec.step_id > beginstep OR UPPER(sql_rec.always_run) = 'Y' THEN
            errstr := sql_rec.error_message;
            errcode := sql_rec.error_code;
            s := UPPER(sql_rec.sql_text);
            /* Replace parameters with values */

            FOR param_rec IN param_cursor LOOP
                s := replace(s, coalesce(param_rec.param_name, ''), coalesce(param_rec.param_value, ''));
            END LOOP;
            errstr := '';
            errcode := 0;

            BEGIN
                p_start_date := LOCALTIMESTAMP;
                EXECUTE (s);
                PERFORM pg_sleep(ifm_app.get_sleep_parameter());

                IF 'N' <> p_log THEN
                    s1 := substr(s, 1, 4000);
                    INSERT INTO ifm_app.sql_for_batch_log
                    VALUES (p_batch, sql_rec.step_id, s1, errcode, errstr, p_start_date, p_start_date);
                END IF;
                
                --[5035 - Severity CRITICAL - Your code ends a transaction inside a block with exception handlers. Revise your code to move transaction control to the application side and try again.]
                commit;
                --*/
                EXCEPTION
                    WHEN others THEN
                        errstr := SQLERRM;
                        errcode := SQLSTATE;

                        IF UPPER(sql_rec.exit_on_exception) = 'Y' THEN
                          --  [5035 - Severity CRITICAL - Your code ends a transaction inside a block with exception handlers. Revise your code to move transaction control to the application side and try again.]
                            rollback;
                            
                            errstr := CONCAT_WS('', errstr, ' process stopped');
                        END IF;

                        IF 'N' <> p_log THEN
                            s1 := substr(s, 1, 4000);
                            INSERT INTO ifm_app.sql_for_batch_log
                            VALUES (p_batch, sql_rec.step_id, s1, errcode, errstr, p_start_date, p_start_date);
                            
                            --[5035 - Severity CRITICAL - Your code ends a transaction inside a block with exception handlers. Revise your code to move transaction control to the application side and try again.]
                            commit;
                            
                        END IF;

                        IF UPPER(sql_rec.exit_on_exception) = 'Y' THEN
                            RAISE;
                        END IF;
            END;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Is that a function or a procedure? You can not commit inside a function in Postgres

Comment: It is stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is creative, but the problem is here:

```
BEGIN
    [...]
    commit;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
        [...]
END;
```

When you enter a `BEGIN` / `END` block that has an `EXCEPTION` handler, PostgreSQL starts a *subtransaction*. `COMMIT` would close a subtransaction, so you cannot commit there. If you think about it, it is the only way to do that correctly, since everything after the `BEGIN` needs to be rolled back if you enter the exception handler.  I know that Oracle does not care about transactional integrity in such a case, but PostgreSQL does.

My advice is to remove the `COMMIT` statements. It doesn't look like you really need them. Otherwise, you have to move the outer loop to client code and commit there.

Comment: Thank you for the input Laurenz Albe. Let me try with your suggestions

Comment: Should i remove the ROLLBACK as well @Laurenz Albe

Comment: Yes. Either not catch the exception (be more specific than `WHEN OTHERS`) or re-raise the exception with `RAISE;` so that you can catch the error on the client side and roll back.

Comment: Thank you @Laurenz Albe.